# regex: how to write a regex matching all strings of Xs that x repeated 5^n times?

Tags: regex

regex: how to write a regex matching all strings of `Xs` that x repeated `5^n` times?

e.g.

> x{5},x{25},x{125}...will pass and x{10}...will not.

```
xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x....x 125 times will pass..etc
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: This is not possible unless you are using a programming language, and can use loops. You can only do *multiples of 5* with Regex, not powers

Comment: I have a gut feeling that similar approach of finding prime number in regex can be used.... still trying to figure out :P  is this question a puzzle actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, some programming language must be used too.
Example in java:

```
    double poweredNumber = 5.0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.[xX])");
    String inputText = "aX bX cX dX eX fX gX hX iX jX kX lX mX nX oX pX rX sX tX uX yX wX vX zX Ax Bx Cx Dx Ex Fx Gx Hx Ix Jx Kx Lx Mx Nx Ox Px Rx Sx Tx Ux Yx Wx Vx Zx";
    
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
    double power = 1.0;
    int nextPatternIndex = (int) Math.pow(poweredNumber, power);
    
    int foundIndex = 0;
    while(m.find())
    {
        foundIndex ++;
        if(foundIndex == nextPatternIndex)
        {
            System.out.println("Found " + m.group(1) + " for Pattern Index: " + foundIndex);
            power ++;
            nextPatternIndex = (int) Math.pow(poweredNumber, power);
        }
    }
```

Result:

> Found eX for Pattern Index: 5
>
> Found Ax for Pattern Index: 25